# Prove if a = ab then b =1

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I am self-studying Theodore Faticoni's 'The Mathematics of Infinity: A Guide to Great Ideas' (John Wiley and Sons, 2nd edition, 2012) as an introduction to set theory. I have close to no experience writing proofs and am having trouble with an early exercise (p. 14):

"Give a highly detailed proof that if a=ab then b=1"

I'm tempted to divide both sides by 'a' and call it good, but I'm assuming this isn't "highly detailed." How do I make this rigorous?

So far no axioms/postulates have been presented (these are from the first chapter, simply called 'Logic'). Not really sure what I can assume. Existence of multiplicative inverse? Existence of multiplicative identity?

Another similar question: Give a highly detailed proof that If x^2 - 1 = 0, then x is a member of {-1,1}.

**EDIT**

Ok I want to see if I can do a solid (logical rather than arithmetic) proof for the second problem I mentioned in the original post.

Given the statements
P: x^2-1 = 0, and
Q: x is a member of {-1,1};
Prove: If P then Q.

We will begin with a logically equivalent statement: (not P) or Q, which can be read: either x^2 - 1 ≠ 0, or x is a member of {-1,1}.

We assume x^2 - 1 = 0 is true, hence, (not P) is false.

Thus, Q must be true by definition of the connective 'or.'

If P and Q are both true, then P implies Q.

P and Q are both true.

P implies Q.

It seems to me these two problems are not formulated well. But I think this is a sufficient solution. It surely is not 'highly detailed' in the arithmetic sense, but I am hoping that as a solution to a logical problem it is sound?

Comment: In what algebraic structure would you like to solve that problem?

Comment: I wish I knew how to answer this question. Total noob studying this topic as a philosophy student. Honestly any example of a correct proof would be helpful.

Comment: I assume it is the field of real numbers. You ahve to assume that $a \neq 0$, otherwise the statement is not true. If $a \neq 0$, then it has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$. Multiply both sides of $ab=a$ from the left by $a^{-1}$ and use that $a^{-1}ab=(a^{-1}a)b=1\cdot b=b$ and $a^{-1}a=1$.

Comment: You cannot prove anything that isn't well-defined. Does it state what kind of numbers $a$ and $b$ are? Does it state how multiplication is defined? Does it state what $1$ is? Without such definitions there is nothing to prove. [edit: I just found the book, and would suggest to skip these two exercises, they don't make sense without context, and indeed no context is given]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was kinda feeling I should just skip - no definition of any mathematical concepts, aside from some brief discussion of predicate logic and truth tables. Couldn't see how I was supposed to say anything!

Comment: Don't get hung up on this early exercise. Your suggestion is good enough at this point. If you want to learn the basic methods of proof, I suggest you download some proof-checking software. They are good for getting you started writing proofs. It's nice to get the immediate feedback on your efforts, especially when self-studying.

Comment: BTW my "highly detailed" proof for that exercise took 32 lines of formal proof, with axioms and definitions, etc. I can't believe the author intended you to get that involved! He also should have told you to assume that $a\neq 0$.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot prove something from nothing. Every proof is based on axioms, definitions and assumptions, and without those there is nothing one can prove. If no context is given (like here), then no proof can be given either.

Especially an exercise that asks you to prove that "if $a=ab$, then $b=1$" requires to state specifically what the symbols mean. Notably, it cannot be proved for the most elementary interpretation, where we are talking about natural (or real) numbers, since it is actually **false**: $0=0\cdot 0$ is a counterexample. If we let $a=0$ and $b=0$, then $a=ab$ is true, but $b=1$ is obviously false.

Comment: Maybe I should read a different book on set theory... good point

Comment: I recommend "Mathematical Proofs" by Chartrand, Polimeni & Zhang as an introduction to proving mathematical statements. For an introduction to logic, you could take a look at Enderton's "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic".

Comment: @Jeremy Given that this is a book on set theory - i.e. on the foundations of mathematics - maybe the entire point of the exercise was to realize that it is not a well-posed problem.

Comment: This answer seems to have confused arithmetical derivation and logical derivation which is the author's intent in the given exercise.

Comment: @TankutBeygu I'm not sure what you're aiming at, but at least my answer doesn't state that $a>ab$ is impossible...

Answer (score -3):

A student's rule of thumb: A sure hint to an exercise is the chapter and the section it is located.

The exercise you have mentioned is at the end of the section on tautologies of the first chapter of the book introducing elementary logic. Evidently, basic arithmetical content is assumed - not Peano Arithmetic, etc.)

For the task: Each proposition has to be dealt *separately*. Otherwise, it would not be a proposition of the calculus and the proof would be directly arithmetical without an appeal to logical form.

Also check for a tautology equivalent to the form of the statement in question to make the task easier.

As an example (you choose the notation you find appropriate):

An equivalent tautology is '(not *P*) or *Q*'. Thus, we have

$``\text{not } a = ab"\text{    or    }``b=1"$

Take the proposition '(not *P*)' by itself:

If $a \neq ab$ then either $a > ab$, which is not arithmetically possible (as in the example 1.4.3, we take $a, b\in\mathbb{N}$ as nonzero), or $a < ab$. Then, $1 < b$.

We have been given that $a = ab$. Then, *Q* is true: $b=1$

There is a hidden lesson in this exercise: In mathematical logic, some statements appear so obvious, even trivial; however, its proof turns out to be very hard or, the statement itself turns out to be false. Hence, the utmost rigour is required.

Comment: "Evidently, basic arithmetic is assumed" -- I don't find this evident at all. The whole point of logic is to become astutely aware of the assumptions and context one is working in, and not to make arbitrary guesses based on intuition instead of reasoning. Your proof does not work: $a>ab$ is arithmetically possible, simply take $b=0$.

Comment: I'm commenting that you are making assumptions about the writer's intent, which is just an example of bad mathematics. And that you then proceed to "prove" a false statement, using the argumentation that "$a>ab$ is arithmetically impossible", something which is not only blatantly false, but also in no way setting a good example of how to use formal logic. Concluding your answer with "the utmost rigour is required" while displaying a complete lack of rigour is not helpful, hence my downvote.

Comment: It seems to me that the statements "$a > ab$ is impossible" and "$a < ab$ implies $b<1$", even assuming $a,b \in \mathbb{N}^+$, are highly nontrivial to prove on their own. The former probably requires some form of induction, while the latter seems to require division (and if you can use division, why not just use it right away?). Your argument therefore doesn't seem to have the rigor that the textbook asks for.

Comment: @TankutBeygu I agree with your take. Here's my attempt: 

Given: ab = a,
Prove: if ab = a, then b = 1. 
Let P be the statement ab = a, and Q be the statement b = 1. 

We must prove that P implies Q .

We can make a different, but logically equivalent statement: Either P is false, or Q is true, which means: either ab ≠ a or b = 1. 

Since we are given: ab=a, then P is not false, meaning Q must be true (by definition of the connective 'or'). Thus, the statement b=1 is true. 

Is this sufficient?

Comment: I think that gets at the point of the exercise... but of course if we let a=0, then arithmetically, ab=1 is immediately false regardless of the value of b. But does my answer get at the point the author is trying to make, in your opinion?

Comment: @Jeremy That's right! Just a tiny notice: you've written ". . . P is not false . . .", delete "not". Perhaps the author should have emphasised these points clearly - he seems to leave these to the examples. Then, with quantifiers, the same: Follow the forms.